# Open branch when clicking on a node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tree, jstree

I'm stuck with [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) here. So far it works and i can browse and expand nodes with the [+] icon and open pages when clicking a node, BUT i still want it to expand all the immediate nodes whenever someone clicks on a node.

i had a look at around for at least 2 hours but couln't find anything. the official website is not very helpfull because they don't have enough examples, and its not very well documented. had a look at this one, but didn't work for me either:
http://luban.danse.us/jazzclub/javascripts/jquery/jsTree/reference/_examples/2_operations.html

i didn't even get an error message in firebug

so here is how my code looks right now,
tree init:

```
$(function () {
    $("#jstree").jstree({
    ....
```

function triggered by click on node

```
.delegate("a","click", function (e) { 
    //click on node
    var page_id = $(this).parent().attr("page_id");
    var idn = $(this).parent().attr("id").split("_")[1];
    /*
            dosnt seem to work either...
    $(this).jstree("openNode", $("#node_"+idn));
    $(this).jstree("openNode", "#node_"+idn);
    */
    page = "index.php?page_id="+page_id;
    //location.href = page;
})
```

.bind didnt work either:

```
$(this).bind("open_node.jstree", function (event, data) { 
    if((data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj)).length) { 
        data.inst._get_parent(data.rslt.obj).open_node(this, false); 
    } 
})
```

does anyone see what i'm missing here...?

Answer (score 38):

You need to bind to select_node.jstree and call toggle_node on the tree instance when it's triggered:

For jsTree versions < 3.0:

```
$("#your_tree").bind("select_node.jstree", function(event, data) {
  // data.inst is the tree object, and data.rslt.obj is the node
  return data.inst.toggle_node(data.rslt.obj);
});
```

For jsTree versions >= 3.0

```
$("#your_tree").bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    return data.instance.toggle_node(data.node);
});
```

Comment: Worked, thanks! But the parameters are different in >= 3.
See: http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=select_node.jstree&f=select_node.jstree

It's `function (node, selected, event)` now.

Comment: Nick, can you expand on the updated version of the function you used so that I may update the answer?  In your change with the new arguments, what is the new toggle_node call?   `data.instance.toggle_node(node);` ?

Answer (score 5):

With a newer version of jsTree (3.0.0 according to jsTree.js), i had to change the code provided by @justind a bit to work:

```
$("#jstree").bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    return data.instance.toggle_node(data.node);
});
```

Comment: I'd prefer to sticking with the API using `$(e.currentTarget).jstree('toggle_node', data.node)` instead of internal things like `.instance`

Answer (score 1):

I use this (casoUso is the page linked, fInvocaCasoUso is a function to make the call).

```
  $("#demo1").bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data)
                    {
                        if (data.rslt.obj.attr("casoUso")!=undefined)
                        {
                            fInvocaCasoUso(data.rslt.obj.attr("casoUso"));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#demo1").jstree("toggle_node",data.rslt.obj);
                        }
                    });
```

If the node has a link, it opens, if not, the sub-tree is opened. Anyway, you should be able to combine both sides of "if" to open the branch and execute your link.
Maybe executing:

```
       $("#demo1").jstree("toggle_node",data.rslt.obj);
       fInvocaCasoUso(data.rslt.obj.attr("casoUso"));
```

Would do it...